# Opensips Tls and certificates issues

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, server, sip, opensips

I am trying to setup the certificate verification in opensips along with the blink sip client. I followed the tutorial:

https://github.com/antonraharja/book-opensips-101/blob/master/content/3.2.%20SIP%20TLS%20Secure%20Calling.mediawiki

My config look like so:

```
[opensips.cfg]
disable_tls = no
listen = tls:my_ip:5061
tls_verify_server= 0
tls_verify_client = 1
tls_require_client_certificate = 1
#tls_method = TLSv1
tls_method = SSLv23
tls_certificate = "/usr/local/etc/opensips/tls/server/server-cert.pem"
tls_private_key = "/usr/local/etc/opensips/tls/server/server-privkey.pem"
tls_ca_list = "/usr/local/etc/opensips/tls/server/server-calist.pem"
```

So i generated the rootCA and the server certificate. Then i took the server-calist.pem added the server-privkey.pem in there (otherwise blink sip client won't load it) and set it in client. I also set the server-calist.pem as a certificate authority in the blink. But when i try to login to my server i get:

```
Feb  4 21:02:42 user /usr/local/sbin/opensips[28065]: DBG:core:tcp_read_req: Using the global ( per process ) buff
Feb  4 21:02:42 user /usr/local/sbin/opensips[28065]: DBG:core:tls_update_fd: New fd is 17
Feb  4 21:02:42 user /usr/local/sbin/opensips[28065]: ERROR:core:tls_accept: New TLS connection from 130.85.9.114:48253 failed to accept: rejected by client
```

So i assume that the client doesn't accept the server certificate for some reason, although i have the "Verify server" checkbox turned off in my blink sip client! I think i have the wrong certificate authority file.

```
./user/user-cert.pem
./user/user-cert_req.pem
./user/user-privkey.pem
./user/user-calist.pem     <- this 4 are for using opensips as a client i think
./rootCA/certs/01.pem
./rootCA/private/cakey.pem
./rootCA/cacert.pem
./server/server-privkey.pem
./server/server-calist.pem
./server/server-cert.pem
./server/server-cert_req.pem
./calist.pem
```

Can anybody help, did i do something wrong i the config or did i use the wrong certificate chain? What certificate exactly should be used by the client as a client cert, and ca authority cert?

Comment: I have the impression that the SSL_accept() is actually failing on the server side! Could you try cleaning up your Blink certificates, and let it use the ones from your OpenSIPS?

Comment: @LiviuChircu i will try it and tell you what i get

Comment: @LiviuChircu  i removed the 'tls' folder from the blink program files folder, and added server-calist.pem with server-privkey.pem as an account key, and server-calist.pem (which is the same as /rootCA/cacert.pem) as a certificate authority file.  I stil get the same  `Feb  5 01:04:07 user /usr/local/sbin/opensips[30040]: DBG:core:tls_update_fd: New fd is 17
Feb  5 01:04:07 user /usr/local/sbin/opensips[30040]: ERROR:core:tls_accept: New TLS connection from 130.85.9.114:51297 failed to accept: rejected by client`

Comment: @LiviuChircu also the log configuration is:   `debug=6
log_stderror=no
log_facility=LOG_LOCAL0`

Comment: @LiviuChircu i tried placing the wrong pem cert which was generated by asterisk and got the following log  http://pastebin.com/xGmmVeZj  . It still says rejected by client, but i think you right, it's actualy the server side which is closing the connection. I also tried removing all the certificates from blink, and tried again. I got again `rejected by client` but without any verify notifications, which appear when you place the wrong cert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright, i'm still not sure if it is working or not, because the authorization behaviour became weird, but after it's hanging for 5-6 minutes i get the success authorization, so this is a solution:

Generate rootCA:

```
opensipsctl tls rootCA
```

then edit `server.conf` file in your `tls` opensips folder and set the `commonName = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is your server ip address. Other variables can be edited in any way. Generate the certificates signed by CA

```
opensipsctl tls userCERT server
```

This will produce 4 files. Download the server-calist.pem, server-cert.pem, server-privkey.pem. Open the server-privkey.pem, copy it's content and paste in the file server-cert.pem, before the actual certificate. If you are using blink, the produced server-cert.pem goes in the preferences->account->advanced. And server-calist.pem goes into the preferences->advanced. After that restart blink and after 5-6 minutes your account is gonna be logged in. But i'v observed a weird behaviour, if you run another copy of blink and try to log into the other existing account **after** your logged from the first one with the certificates, you can log in from other account without providing the certificates. So i don't know, but i think it's working.

P.S. I asked about the certificates in the opensips mailing list, but i guess they found my question too lame, so i didn't get the response. If you have the same problem and got better results or an answer from opensips support let me know please.